# What does "tangent" mean in "tangent space".

Tags: differential-geometry

What does tangent mean in the expression "tangent space"
$$
x_i \in \mathbb{R}
$$
and
$$
p = (x_1,\ldots,x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n
$$
And the "tangent space" is
$$
\mathbb{R}_p^n = T_p\mathbb{R}^n
$$
is
$$
\{\vec{v}_p = (a_1,\ldots,a_n) \mid a_i \in \mathbb{R}\}
$$

What's the significance of the word "tangent"?  We've spoken of
no hyperplane or curve for anything to be tangent to....

I'm beginning to think that we're talking about a set of vectors
with origins at $p$ and we're calling it tangent just to have a
specific name for it.

what am i missing?
thx.

Comment: Sure we have, it's tangent to $\Bbb R^n$ inside $\Bbb R^n$. Think of it as a special case of $\Bbb R^m$ inside $\Bbb R^m$, each point of which has the same tangent space (namely $\Bbb R^m$ itself), which itself may be interpreted as a limiting case of say .. spheres of bigger and bigger radius (when $m<n$ anyway).

Comment: Tangent space of a manifold: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space The tangent space of $\mathbb R^n$ however is $\mathbb R^n$, but we think of the first one as a space of points and the latter as a space of vectors.

Comment: Have a look at (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1291460)

Comment: The origin is perfectly clear and can be traced back to the founding father, Gauss: it is the tangent plane when your manifold is a surface embedded in $\mathbb{R^3}$. It must be set in a historical perspective: gradually, as the concept of manifold has evolved towards an abstract point of view, the tangent space has followed the same trend. Nevertheless, the tangent vectors, explained as derivatives, can be connected to, say the speed vectors for curves traced on a surface. It happens that keeping only this aspect is enough to retrieve all the "good" properties of a "concrete" tangent plane.

Comment: "Noob question" has not to be part of a title. A title must contain all the important information and only it.